# chained promises in nodejs is executing only the first promise but not chained promises

Tags: node.js

I have below code in nodejs. I have two promises chained and then by console message done at the end.

```
    const myPromisedFunction = () => {
        console.log('my promised function');
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => resolve, 1000);
        });
    };


    myPromisedFunction().then(() => myPromisedFunction()).then(() => console.log('done'));
```

when I run the program I get output as `my promised function` only once.
But I expect twice followed by `done` message.

`node` version I'm using is v.8.15.0

Any idea what is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`resolve()` instead of `resolve` in the setTimeoutFn

Answer (score 1):

Or you can do it even simplier

```
const myPromisedFunction = () => {
    console.log('my promised function');
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(resolve, 1000);
    });
};


myPromisedFunction().then(myPromisedFunction).then(() => console.log('done'));
```

Use `resolve` instead of `() => resolve` and `myPromisedFunction` instead of `() => myPromisedFunction`